# How to add days to DATE value in SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have to write an Update statement that modifies the shipped date field in my table. 
I need to modify the shipped date field to add 3 more days to the current shipped date for orders that have a shipped country of Germany.

My question is how do i add 3 more days like that? Also for this statement i have below i am getting and error that says incorrect syntax near the keyword where. Any suggestions to why would be appreciated

```
UPDATE [dbo].[LMOrders]
 SET [ShippedDate] =
where  ShipCountry = 'Germany'
```

Comment: Just a note: [W3](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) is a good resource for anything sql.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that explains the problem you're having, in a way that will be useful when a future reader here finds it in a search result. "Can you help me with..." won't have any meaning to them, and does nothing to describe a specific problem. Thanks.

Comment: The edit that was given for me omitted the statement that this was for which is the update statement not just any random query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `DATEADD()` function for this:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[LMOrders]
 SET [ShippedDate] = DATEADD("d",3,[ShippedDate])
WHERE ShipCountry = 'Germany'
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me